# Result in bad request exception when sending json object to HTTP server in android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm trying to send this HTTP server but I get an exception. this is the code I'm using in my asynctask, I feel like I have missed something thats why it gives the exception because I get success in fiddler when I try my request. If anyone could spot the mistake please help me with it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**This is my request,**

```
{"CartItemEntity":[{"MainMenuCode":"CHBA","SubMenuCode":"AL","Quantity":1,"Price":1560}],"DiscountCode":"0","PayCode":"0","OrderID":"6592","OutletCode":"AT","RequiredDate":"15/6/2015","Total":"1638.0","CardNo":"0","PhoneNo":1234}
```

**This is the asynctask class**

```
public class GetAllDiscountsAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, JSONArray> {
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    private JSONArray responseJson = null;
    private Context contxt;

    public GetAllDiscountsAsyncTask(Context context, OnTaskCompleted listener) {

        // API = apiURL;
        this.contxt = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    JSONObject jData;


    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(JSONObject... jData) {

        String parameterPass = jData.toString();
        Log.i("doInBackground", parameterPass);

        String path = null;
        String response = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;

        try {
            path = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            new URL(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(path);
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jData.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = httpClient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            responseJson = new JSONArray(response);
            System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + responseJson.length());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            responseJson = new JSONArray(response);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return responseJson;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        listener.onTaskCompleted(responseJson);
    }

}
```

This is the exception I get,

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is JSONArray and not JSONObject ?

Comment: @Sachin Gadagi I have updated my question by adding my request, That is a json object right?

Comment: I think you should see the exact request that is being sent when making the request from fiddler and see if everything is the same on the java side.

Comment: its same, Im getting data to put in fiddler from system out in java code

Comment: I'm getting addition [ ] bracket. ( [ is at the beginning and ] at the end), how can I remove that square bracket

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the response to String and then make a JSON object out of it

Comment: value of response in this line is null, response = httpClient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);